# Using HTML 5 on node.js server the post body seems to be undefined

Tags: html, node.js

I using an HTML 5 form to make a POST request. But when I receive the request on my node.js `req.on("readable", function(data))` `data` is `undefined`

This is my HTML 5:

```
...
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:3000">
        <input id="user" type="text" readonly/>

        <label> Test1
            <input type="number" name="work" min="0" max="10" required />
        </label>
        <label> Test2
            <input type="number" name="buero" min="0" max="10" required />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
...
```

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {
...
let fileResult = readFileSync("./Result.html", { encoding: "utf8" })
        let body = "";
        req.on("data", (d) => {
            body += d;  // BreakPoint1
        })
        req.on("readable", function (d) {
            body += d;  // BreakPoint2
        })
        req.on("end", () => {
            handlePostData(JSON.parse(body))
        })
        res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
        res.write(fileResult)
        res.end();
...
```

I am wondering why it does only run into BreakPoint2, I was expecting it would run into BreakPoint1. But when its running into BreakPoint2, `d` is `undefined`.

If I change the `method`to `GET` req.url is as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`readable`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_readable) event doesn't provide data to the callback.  You have to get it manually with `this.read()`.